# Descriptor Protocol with custom __str__() method in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, repr, python-descriptors

**UPDATED Question**: In Python, can I create a custom data structure that is a `dict`, but which I get and set as a `set`, and for which I can create a custom `__str__` representation?

I want a class attribute that is structurally a dict{str:list[str]}, but which the user-interface (for lack of better words) treats like a set[str]. And I want to print it like a dict with custom formatting.

**Attempted Solution**:
I implemented a Descriptor, but I haven't figured out how to customize the `__str__`, so I'm thinking a Descriptor is not actually what I should be trying.

```py
class TreatDictLikeSet():  # The Descriptor I wish existed
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None) -> object:
        my_dict = obj.__dict__.get(self.name) or {}
        return [e for v in my_dict.values() for e in v]

    def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
        value = ...<rules to insert set values into a dict>...
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = value


class Foo():
    my_dict = TreatDictLikeSet()
```

Comment: Please fix your question so that the code is actually syntactically valid and functional. It is also confusing because it seems like parts of the code you show are unrelated to your question about the `__str__` method. I suggest you read the article on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76300262/edit) your question accordingly. Also please decide what your actual question is because this reads like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this via a descriptor, rather than writing a proper data structure class that *is* a dict while printing like a set (or vice versa)? The `__str__` method needs to be on the thing *returned* by any descriptor, which might make having the descriptor a waste of time.

Comment: @Blckknght it's possible that all I need to do is create a custom data structure rather than use Descriptors. Your feedback is helpful in that sense. I guess I'm struggling to find a good resource on how to write a proper data structure.

Comment: @Blckknght and what do you mean by "The `__str__` method needs to be on the thing returned by any descriptor"? "On the thing"? Can you please refer explicitly to the example I wrote (or provide a better example)?

Comment: @yetixhunting You have it backwards, I'm afraid. _You_ should provide a clearer example of what exactly you want. :)

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Thanks I updated the question :) But I'll let Blckknght respond for himself

Comment: So you could emulate the `set` API by implementing `add`, `remove`, `union` and similar methods, as well as `__contains__`, `__iter__` and of course, the `__str__` method that you want to behave more like a dict. But I'd note that if you want the set's values to be the values of your dictionary, you're not going to have any way of implementing `__contains__` and `remove` efficiently, since the hashing in the set and the hashing in the dict are going to be on different values (since dicts hash their keys, not their values).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the behavior *"assign `set`, but get `dict`"*, I am not sure you need to deal with descriptors at all.

Seems like a simple `property` would do just fine:

```py
class Foo:
    _my_set: set[str]

    @property
    def my_dict(self) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
        return {f"key_{i}": [value] for i, value in enumerate(self._my_set)}

    @my_dict.setter
    def my_dict(self, value: set[str]) -> None:
        self._my_set = value


foo = Foo()
foo.my_dict = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
print(f"{foo.my_dict}")  # {'key_0': ['a'], 'key_1': ['c'], 'key_2': ['b']}
```

---

#### Update

If you want something that behave like a standard collection class (e.g. a `set`), a good starting point is usually the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) module.

For example, you could subclass `MutableSet`, implement its abstract methods (`__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`, `add`, and `discard`), and also implement your own `__init__` **and `__str__`** methods for it:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator, MutableSet
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class SetButAlsoDictOfLists(MutableSet[T]):
    _data: dict[str, list[T]]

    def __init__(self, values: Iterable[T] = ()) -> None:
        self._data = {}
        for value in values:
            self.add(value)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self._data)

    def __contains__(self, value: object) -> bool:
        return any(value in list_ for list_ in self._data.values())

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return (list_[0] for list_ in self._data.values())

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._data)

    def add(self, value: T) -> None:
        self._data[f"key_{value}"] = [value]

    def discard(self, value: T) -> None:
        del self._data[f"key_{value}"]
```

As you wished, the underlying data structure is a dictionary of lists. I just implemented some arbitrary rule for creating the dictionary keys here for demonstration purposes.

As @Blckknght pointed out in a comment, the fact that you are using a different data structure underneath means that the runtime of operations can be very different. Specifically, as you can see, the way I implemented `__contains__` here is in *O(n)* as opposed to *O(1)* with actual sets. This is because I am looping over the entire `values` view of the `dict` to find some value instead of just hashing and looking up as I would with a set.

On the other hand, even though deletion in principle would be just as expensive, due to *this specific* implementation of the `dict` keys logic, removal (`discard`) is just as efficient because the value is part of the key.

You could of course store the values in an *actual* set alongside the dictionary, thus making these operations efficient again, but this would obviously take up twice as much memory for each value.

Either way, you can use this class as a regular (mutable) set now, but its string representation is that of the underlying dictionary:

```py
obj = SetButAlsoDictOfLists({"a", "b", "d"})
print(obj.isdisjoint(["x", "y"]))  # True
obj.add("c")
obj.remove("d")
print(obj)  # {'key_b': ['b'], 'key_a': ['a'], 'key_c': ['c']}
```

Now if you still want that descriptor magic for some reason, you can just write one that uses such a class under the hood, i.e. initializes a new object in its `__set__` and returns it in its `__get__` methods:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

# ... import SetButAlsoDictOfLists

_T = TypeVar("_T")


class Descriptor(Generic[_T]):
    name: str

    def __set_name__(self, owner: type, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __get__(
        self,
        instance: object,
        owner: type | None = None,
    ) -> SetButAlsoDictOfLists[_T]:
        return instance.__dict__.get(self.name, SetButAlsoDictOfLists())

    def __set__(self, instance: object, value: Iterable[_T]) -> None:
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = SetButAlsoDictOfLists(value)
```

And use it like this:

```py
class Foo:
    my_cool_set = Descriptor[str]()


foo = Foo()
print(foo.my_cool_set)  # {}
foo.my_cool_set = {"a", "b"}
print(foo.my_cool_set)  # {'key_b': ['b'], 'key_a': ['a']}
foo.my_cool_set |= ["b", "c"]
print(foo.my_cool_set)  # {'key_b': ['b'], 'key_a': ['a'], 'key_c': ['c']}
```

Comment: I don't want to get dict. I want to (1) get `set`, (2) assign `set`, (3) print as dict, with custom formatting. That's why I thought I needed to implement my own `__str__` somehow.

Comment: And I want the actual data structure object in the background to be a `dict`. Does this make sense (even if sounds unwise)? Is it possible with a custom data structure?

Comment: @yetixhunting I updated my answer. Maybe this will point you in the right direction.